# DRF polymorphic many-to-many with extra fields

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-polymorphic

I'm tinkering around with Django Rest Framework to build an api that can handle Bills of Materials (BoM) of electronic components.

I'm using django-polymorphic and django-rest-polymorphic so I can use polymorphic models for the components (they have shared attributes, but I still want to handle them in much the same way. The polymorphic models are great for this purpose).

All is well and good until I introduce many-to-many relations with a 'through' attribute. What I would like is a BoM that has several different components, each with a quantity, e.g. BoM1 has 2x470k resistor & 3x 100uF capacitor.

models.py: (pruned a bit to keep this post from being an epic novel)

```
class BoM(models.Model):
    """Bill of Materials: a list of all parts and their quantities for a given pedal"""
    pedal = models.ForeignKey(Pedal, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    variant = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    electronic_components = models.ManyToManyField(
        'ElectronicComponent', through='ElectronicComponentQty', blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Bill of materials'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Bills of materials'

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.pedal)


class ElectronicComponent(PolymorphicModel):
    """Shared data model for electronic components"""
    value = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    datasheet = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/components', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.value


class ElectronicComponentQty(models.Model):
    """Combination of resistor and quantity"""
    bom = models.ForeignKey(BoM, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    component = models.ForeignKey(
        ElectronicComponent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Elecronic component quantity'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Electronic component quantities'


class Resistor(ElectronicComponent):
    """Resistor data model"""
    WATTAGES = [('1/4w', '1/4w'), ('1/8w', '1/8w')]

    wattage = models.CharField(max_length=4, choices=WATTAGES, default='1/4w')



class Capacitor(ElectronicComponent):
    """Capacitors (all kinds)"""
    VOLTAGE_RATINGS = [
        ('16V', '16V'),
        ('35V/50V', '35V/50V'),
    ]

    CAP_TYPES = [
        ('ceramic disk', 'ceramic disk'),
        ('film', 'film'),
        ('electrolytic', 'electrolytic'),
        ('tantalum', 'tantalum'),
        ('other', 'other'),
    ]

    capacitor_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=20, choices=CAP_TYPES, default='film')
    voltage_rating = models.CharField(
        max_length=10, choices=VOLTAGE_RATINGS, blank=True)
```

serializers.py:

```
class ElectronicComponentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ElectronicComponent
        fields = '__all__'


class ElectronicComponentQtySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ElectronicComponentQty
        fields = '__all__'


class BoMSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    electronic_components = ElectronicComponentQtySerializer(
        many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = BoM
        fields = '__all__'

class ResistorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Resistor
        fields = '__all__'


class CapacitorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Capacitor
        fields = '__all__'


class ElectronicComponentPolySerializer(PolymorphicSerializer):
    model_serializer_mapping = {
        Resistor: ResistorSerializer,
        Capacitor: CapacitorSerializer,
    }
```

With this code I can create EletronicComponentQty objects no problem. However, when I try to list the BoM (through the serializer), I get: 
    AttributeError at /pedalparts/boms/
    Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `bom` on 
    serializer `ElectronicComponentQtySerializer`.
    The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any 
    attribute or key on the `Capacitor` instance.
    Original exception text was: 'Capacitor' object has no attribute 
    'bom'.

Anyone know how I can solve this? I'm open to any changes that make this work.

Answer (score 0):

As `electronic_components` on the `BoM` model refers to the `ElectronicComponent` model it should not use the `ElectronicComponentQtySerializer` but one that can serialize the right instances, most likely the `ElectronicComponentSerializer` or the `ElectronicComponentPolySerializer`.